# Cannot send mail with no "From" header Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

i have a library in codeigniter which autoloads

```
<?php
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Send_email {
    private $CI;
    public $from_email;
    public $from_name;
    public $reply_to;
    public $to_email;
    public $subject;
    public $message;
    public function __construct() {
         $this->CI =& get_instance();
         $this->CI->load->library('email');
    }
    public function send_email($f_email,$f_name,$t_email,$rep_to,$sub,$msg){
        $this->from_email = $f_email;
        $this->from_name = $f_name;
        $this->to_email = $t_email;
        $this->reply_to = $rep_to;
        $this->subject = $sub;
        $this->message = $msg;
        $this->CI->email->from($this->from_email, $this->from_name);
        $this->CI->email->to($this->to_email);
        $this->CI->email->reply_to($this->reply_to);
        $this->CI->email->subject($this->subject);
        $this->CI->email->message($this->message);
        $config['protocol'] = "smtp";
        $config['smtp_host'] = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
        $config['smtp_port'] = "465";
        $config['smtp_user'] = "****@gmail.com"; 
        $config['smtp_pass'] = "****";
        $config['protocol'] = 'sendmail';
        $config['mailpath'] = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';
        $config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
        $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
        $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
        $this->CI->email->initialize($config);
        if($this->CI->email->send()){
            return TRUE;
        }else{
            return $this->CI->email->print_debugger();
        }
    }
}
?>
```

and while calling it from controller

```
$this->send_email->send_email(......)
```

After calling this method i am getting this error
Cannot send mail with no "From" header.How can i solve this problem?

Comment: check that are you getting error before this function call or any things is printed or echo before this function call in controller.

Answer (score 0):

Check $this->from_email value coming properly or not

Comment: There is no problem. It has its value

Answer (score -1):

```
echo $this->email->print_debugger();
```

which will return header, subject & body content